# Are the Empire ships at an inherent disadvantage due to lack of shields?

Tags: star-wars-squadrons

I noticed the Empire side doesn't have a shield slot for most ships, while the Rebel side does. The Empire ships have higher base hulls for the ships that don't have shield slots, but is it enough to offset the advantage of the shields?

Comment: I believe they are also faster and more nimble. This, coupled with the extra hull points, may be enough to "level the playing field", but that's largely a matter of opinion is it not?

Comment: @sirreldar agreed, but i was hoping someone more inclined than myself may have gone through the module numbers and done the math. I feel like shields VS no shields is kind of a big deal for a 2 sided multiplayer-only game. With such an obvious difference between teams, I would think they'd put an equally obvious balance-element in there too (e g. Hulls that were proportionally sized to the missing shields). Also, there are shield variants the rebels can use, so its not just shields, but the effects of the shield variants as well, that the Empire is lacking.

Comment: @Dpeif: You can't just set empire hulls equal to republic hull + shield numbers. Shield regens over time, hull doesn't. Then again, hull can be repaired quickly (but with a cooldown), whereas shield either regenerate slowly _or_ require you to divert power away from your offensive capabilities. Over all, it affects how you manage your ship more than actually giving one party an edge over the other. I haven't done the numbers but there is no clear cut _advantage_ to either. It's just different.

Comment: @Flater but rebels can repair *and* regen shields. I acknowledge it's not a clear cut equation, which is why I asked my question in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked this up before, and found out this.  To balance out the shield dilemma, Ties have a special ability called power conversion.  You can instantly give a burst of power to engines or weapons.  giving it to weapons instantly fills the energy guage, allowing you to give sustained fire.  This slows you down, and decreases your mobility.  Giving it to engines fills up your boost instantly allowing you to speed away.  Republic ships can divert power too, but power conversion gives you an instant maximum burst.

Hope this helps. :)